# Rails alert not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to alert a user if they are logged in or not to an app.  Here is my sessions destroy action:

```
  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url, alert: "Logged out!"
  end
```

Pretty strait forward.  One somebody clicks the logout button, I would like an alert to pop u saying "Logged out!".

It isn't showing up, but I also believe I am missing something in the view.  What do I have to do in the views for this to show?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your view template should conditionally render a [flash message](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash.html) if one is in the session. The following snippet will display all `alert` flash messages:

```
<% if flash[:alert] %>
    <div class="alert"><%= flash[:alert] %></div>
<% end %>
```

**UPDATE**:

If, alternatively, you would like to render out *any* flash message type (e.g., `alert`, `notice`, `warning`, etc.), you can use the following snippet to iterate through *any and all* of the flash messages in your session:

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
    <div class="<%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
<% end %>
```

Assuming you utilize more than one flash message type, this latter approach is more dynamic and requires less code to handle than handling each flash message type individually.

Comment: This is a correct answer, if you need a guide you can [check out this one](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash) that has a little more information